# cheerio collection elements have no innerHTML property

Tags: jquery, cheerio

I can't seem to find the `innerHTML` property on elements returned in a cheerio query.

The following works just fine in jQuery, ie it outputs `Para 2`.

```
const d = $("p","<div><p>Para 1</p> <p>Para 2</p></div>");
console.log(d[d.length-1].innerHTML)
```

However, in cheerio, it produces `undefined`, even though each item in `d` has `nodeType` value of 1.

What is the cheerio way of extracting the contents each (other than the first) of the items returned from a selection query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cheerio.load("<div><p>Para 1</p> <p>Para 2</p></div>")('p').last().text()
```

Comment: I need to get the contents of any element. I find that `d.eq(i).html()` where `i` is the index to the collection works pretty reliably. Not sure if this is the official method.

Comment: Holy that was way too hard to find on the internet. `.html() ` was what I was looking for